# Same format different results. Help me understand why CONTAINS returns differently to essentially the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select*
from dbo.Users
where CONTAINS(UEmailLogin,'"email1@mail.com*"')

select *
from dbo.Users
where CONTAINS(UEmailLogin,'"email2@mail.com*"')
```

The first query returns nothing.

The second returns the expected results.

When I remove the asterisk from the search term

i.e

```
'"email1@mail.com"'
```

vs

```
'"email1@mail.com*"'
```

I obtain the expected results.

I am trying to understand what is happening. Both rows returned from the query search of email1 and email2 are almost identical. The only significant difference is the date of their creation. The row containing EmailLogin email2 was created a few months ago, whereas email1 is much more recent.

I have been reading the CONTAINS microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and I have been thinking it might have to do with indexing.

Anyone with knowledge able to provide some insight?

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINS is for full text search

Does your UEmailLogin has value email2@mail.com* or just email2@mail.com ?

You have option to use like query also.

Comment: I do not understand the question. The email in the UEmailLogin column does not have an asterisk appended.
Thanks for the suggestion. I realize I can use a LIKE query. I am trying to understand why CONTAINS is acting as such.